# how to divide a cell into exactly 2 equal rows in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a grid view in which i need to divide a cell into 2 equal rows...

here i can divide but i cannot divide into equal parts....

how can i make a cell exactly into 2 rows....

here is my code..

**UPDATED ONE**

```
<Wizard:WizardGridView ID="gvresmgt" runat="server" AllowPaging="False"       AllowSorting="True" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" WizardCustomPager="False" EnableModelValidation="True"   CssClass="style1" ShowHeader="False" >
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField >
 <ItemStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="left" />
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" Text='<%# Eval("BGP_ID")%>' ></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField >
 <ItemStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDescription" Text='<%# Eval("BGP_DESC")%>' >            </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemStyle Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<ItemTemplate>
**<div id="1" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #C0C0C0">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPlanStart" Font-Bold="true" Text="Projects"></asp:Label>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
               </div>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Font-Bold="true" Text="SubTotal"></asp:Label>  **
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</Wizard:WizardGridView>
```

Comment: @anilpap Dont forget to mark as answer if that answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the height set to half

```
<ItemStyle Width="100px" Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<ItemTemplate>
 <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
   <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPlanStart" Font-Bold="true" Text="Unknown"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPlanStart" Font-Bold="true" Text="Projects"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Font-Bold="true" Text="SubTotal"></asp:Label>    
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fLk4d.jpg

hi here is my grid image ....i can divide into 2 rows ...which looks ugly to make that good ...

i need to divide exactly into 2 rows.....

thank you @anil

Comment: Then try using merge rows instead ..follow this link http://marss.co.ua/MergingCellsInGridView.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView. You can have put any conditions when using merge if you want all rows like this then use constant while merging rows

Comment: thats fine but my grid is in design...so how to change in design mode

Comment: ok thats working but looks like this http://i.imgur.com/4zpdt.jpg i need a line between them i mean between projects and subtotal....because i need some more columns represnting the data...

Comment: @anilpab i think the div style add that line. not sure if you missed that. try `removing` your `custom height & width`

Comment: it does not look good ....help me...i.imgur.com/SEfjx.jpg...i need 2 rows exactly beacause my data contains back ground color...which is dynamic

Comment: Can you update your last attempt in your question...may be i can help

Comment: Why you gave 2 `<br/>` in the div this will make uneven part of cell ?? try with only 1 `<br/>` Also if you want cell color to be dynamic you can set using `<div>` part only assign `runat="server"` to the div and try setting the color from codebehind file

Comment: Ok now there is third row in scene.I have updated the answer and used the table instead. Please check and let me know the results